# Notification system showing ugly Ok-Cancel alert

Tags: release-freya, notifications

Suddenly nice top-right notifications stopped working for some apps (Slack and Music apps for example). An ugly and annoying traditional ok/cancel alert is being show instead.

[image]

Any ideas?

Edit:

`sudo touch /usr/lib/libunity-electron_notification_fix`

Fixes the issue until I restart the computer.

Comment: Are you using daily ppa?

Comment: @bitseater Only elementary-tweaks-daily ppa. Not elementary-os daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this quick workaround

```
sudo touch /usr/lib/libunity-electron_notification_fix
```

Then restart session.